# JPA/Hibernate inserting into non existing table in spring boot application

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am new to spring jpa/boot. I've created one-to-many relationship between `Student` and `StudentCourse` using JPA / Hibernate in a Spring boot application.

The database tables are student and student_course.

When I run the `SchoolApplication.java`, its failing with the error, 'table or view does not exist'.

It is a valid error as I have not created the table, `student_course_list` and only want to insert data in `student` and `student_course` tables.

Please can you advise why hibernate is looking for this additional table and how to resolve this issue?

**Log**

```
Hibernate: 
insert 
into
    student_course_list
    (student, course_list) 
values
    (?, ?)

Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:242) ~[spring-orm-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
```

**SchoolApplication.java**

```
package com.school;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.school.domain.Student;
import com.school.domain.StudentCourse;
import com.school.service.StudentServiceInterface;

@EntityScan(basePackages={"com.school.domain"})
@SpringBootApplication
public class SchoolApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    protected StudentServiceInterface studentService;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SchoolApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {

        StudentCourse sc1 = new StudentCourse();
        sc1.setCourseId(new Long(1));
        sc1.setEndDate(null);

        StudentCourse sc2 = new StudentCourse();
        sc2.setCourseId(new Long(2));
        sc2.setEndDate(null);

        //Course List
        List<StudentCourse> studentCourse = new ArrayList();

        studentCourse.add(sc1);
        studentCourse.add(sc2);

        Student student = new Student();
        student.setFirstName("test first");
        student.setLastName("test last");
        student.setCourseList(studentCourse);

        studentService.saveStudent(student);
}
}
```

**Student**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="student")
public class Student {

    @Id
    @Column(name="student_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO, generator="student_seq_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="student_seq_gen", sequenceName="SEQ_STUDENT")
    private Long studentId;

    @OneToMany( targetEntity=StudentCourse.class, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL} )
    private List<StudentCourse> courseList;

    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name="gender")
    private char gender;

    @Column(name="date_of_birth")
    private Date dateOfBirth;

    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name="city")
    private String city;

    // getter and setters
    .....
    .....
```

**StudentCourse**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="student_course")
public class StudentCourse {

    @Id
    @Column(name="student_course_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO, generator="student_course_seq_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="student_course_seq_gen", sequenceName="SEQ_STUDENT_COURSE")
    private Long studentCourseId;

    @Column(name="student_id")
    private Long studentId;

    @Column(name="course_id")
    private Long courseId;

    @Column(name="end_date")
    private Date endDate;

    // getter and setters
    .....
    .....
```

UPDATE:

**StudentCourse.java:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="student_course")
public class StudentCourse {

    @Id
    @Column(name="student_course_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO, generator="student_course_seq_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="student_course_seq_gen", sequenceName="SEQ_STUDENT_COURSE")
    private Long studentCourseId;

    @JoinColumn(name="student_id", nullable = false, updatable = false, insertable = true)
    @ManyToOne
    private Student student;

    @Column(name="course_id")
    private Long courseId;

    @Column(name="end_date")
    private Date endDate;
```

Comment: Your entities were not being scanned by the application.  Are you using Spring Data JPA repository?

Comment: @Rae, I am using jpa dependency, -----------<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
  </dependency>--------- shall i use ------------<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>------- instead?

Comment: You haven't told hibernate how to persist the relation so it assumes it needs an additional table. You only have `Long studentId` in your `StudentCourse` the same for `Long courseId`. Those should be a `Student` and `Course` object and then you can add `mappedBy=`student` onto the `@OneToMany`.

Comment: @M.Deinum, sorry, I didn't get it. please can you elaborate in an answer?

Comment: There is already an answer explaining just that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't define a `JoinColumn` (or `JoinTable` for `ManyToMany`) for your relationship. Hibernate is trying to create a table your student.courseList relationship property.

Change your Student class as follows:

```
// You shouldn't need targetEntity, as your collection has the TargetEntity.
// this parameter is only needed if the Generic type is not present 
// (e.g. private List courseList)
@OneToMany( cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, mappedBy = "student" )
private List<StudentCourse> courseList;
```

Change your StudentCourse class as follows:

```
// Replace studentId with a Relationship
@JoinColumn(name="student_id")
@ManyToOne
private Student student;
```

This will tell Hibernate that the Relationship for Student -> StudentCourse is owned by Student and mapped by the student_id column in the student_course table.

Comment: its working but not populating student_id in student_course table.

Comment: Did you set the `Student` in the `StudentCourse?` Can you provide an example of what you're doing and seeing?

Comment: Yes, I've made the suggested changes. also, added some additional attributes (nullable = false, updatable = false, insertable = true) please see updated StudentCourse.java. Its inserting data into student and student_course table but student_id (foreign key) is not getting inserted.

Comment: You need to set the student in the StudentCourse before you save the student. Like `sc1.setStudent(student)`. You should probably also make the StudentCourse.course a relationship as well. Use the same pattern.

Comment: Another note, the nullable, etc. properties you set aren't validated at run time. They are used for hibernate ddl generation. If you want to validate at runtime, you need to add the java.persistence.validation annotations, such as `@NotNull`.

Answer (score 0):

You're not telling your application to scan for the entities.  On your main class add the `@EntityScan` annotation. e.g.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan(basePackages={"com.example.model", "com.example.student.model"})
public class SchoolApplication implements CommandLineRunner {
    ...
}
```

BTW, `@ComponentScan` is redundant, `@SpringBootApplication` is enough.  If you're gonna look inside the `SpringBootApplication` class you'll see `@ComponentScan` there.

Comment: Why is adding EntityScan necessary? Because he has a transaction in his run method? Or what is the reason?

Comment: I've added the @EntityScan but still getting same error

Comment: This is not required as long as the `@SpringBootApplication` is in a parent package to your entities and you have the Spring JPA libraries in your dependency list.